# Getting current bitrate with CAF

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

With the new CAF framework for creating Chromecast applications I see there is a new event that gets fired each time the bitrate changes. This is great but it doesn't cover all of my needs.

Is there a way to obtain the current bitrate using the `playerManager` or the `MPL` directly while using CAF?

Comment: Just my opinion. So far, [`cast.framework.events.BitrateChangedEvent`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.events.BitrateChangedEvent) is the only reference provided by Google Cast SDK regarding bitrate.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this in the docs, but I found out that the bitrate is included in `playerManager.getStats()`.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.PlayerManager#getStats